# trigger WebSocket in Flask from external event

Tags: python, websocket, flask

Is there a way to trigger the `send()` websocket command based on a external event? I am trying to push to the client every time a database is updated. I've tried using an sql `notify`, a uwsgi file monitor decorator etc. Basic code is

```
from flask.ext.uwsgi_websocket import GeventWebSocket
from uwsgidecorators import *

ws = GeventWebSocket(app)

@ws.route('/feed')
def socket(ws):
    ws_readystate = ws.receive()
    if ws_readystate == '1':
        ws.send(json.dumps('this message is received just fine'))
        # client is ready, start something to trigger sending a message here
        @filemon("../mydb.sqlite")
        def db_changed(x):
            print 'DB changed'
            ws.send(json.dumps('db changed'))
```

this will print "DB changed" in output, but client won't recieve the 'db changed' message. I'm running the app as

```
uwsgi --master --http :5000 --http-websockets --gevent 2 --wsgi my_app_name:app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gevent queues are a great way to manage such patterns

This is an example you can adapt to your situation

```
from uwsgidecorators import *
from gevent.queue import Queue

channels = []

@filemon('/tmp',target='workers')
def trigger_event(signum):
    for channel in channels:
        try:
            channel.put_nowait(True)
        except:
            pass

def application(e, sr):
    sr('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    yield "Hello and wait..."
    q = Queue()
    channels.append(q)
    q.get()
    yield "event received, goodbye"
    channels.remove(q)
```

if you dot not plan to use multiple processes feel free to remove target='workers' from the filemon decorator (this special target raise the uwsgi signal to all of the workers instead of the first avilable one)